# How to read data from SSBO into main memory?

Tags: c++, memory, gpgpu, vulkan

One can initialize an SSBO buffer on VRAM in a fairly straightforward manner.

- Create the data into some RAM buffer (e.g. an stl vector)
- Create a buffer handle (i.e. VkBuffer) and attach it to some memory on your device. Because I am lazy I use VMA:

```
    VmaAllocationCreateInfo alloc_info = {};
    alloc_info.usage = VMA_MEMORY_USAGE_CPU_TO_GPU;
    VmaAllocation allocation;
    vk::Buffer staging_buffer;
    VkResult result = vmaCreateBuffer(
        vma_allocator,
        (VkBufferCreateInfo*)&buffer_info,
        &alloc_info,
        (VkBuffer*)&staging_buffer,
        &allocation,
        nullptr);
```

- Then you use your logical device to get a pointer into which to copy your data and associate it to your handle:

  ```
   void* data;
   DEBUG_VAR(vk::Result result =)
   device.mapMemory(
       staging_buffer_allocation.deviceMemory,
       staging_buffer_allocation.offset,
       buffer_size,
       MemoryMapFlags(0),
       &data);
  ```
- Finally you treat that pointer as you would any old C pointer and copy your data:

```
      memcpy(data, object, buffer_size);
      device.unmapMemory(staging_buffer_allocation.deviceMemory);
```

Assume we use this logic to create an SSBO and we modify its data on a compute shader. We are interested in fetching this data on the CPU side.

How do you read the data from VRAM into RAM?

Comment: "*Assume we use this logic to create an SSBO*" That's a big assumption. The implementation doesn't have to *let you*. Remember: you can use Vulkan's memory in only the ways it allows you to, so you have to ask how it will let you. Implementations don't have to let you create SSBOs in host-visible memory, for example.

Comment: Well, assume I am on a device that does let me (because I am and portability is not an issue).

Comment: I don't understand the question. You have already shown how to copy data between CPU and GPU.

Comment: That copies from cpu onto gpu, I want to do the opposite, copy it from gpu onto cpu

Comment: That's the same, you just swap src and dst in `memcpy`?